# htaccess redirect issue folder vs file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Trying to setup a permanent 301 redirect using the htaccess file. I want to redirect all traffic from the `events` folder to the `events.html` file. I'd usually use something like this...

```
Redirect 301 /events/ /events.html
```

Unfortunately, it’s not working. Using the above, I receive an error and can’t visit the `events.html` page. How do I make a distinction between the folder and page of the same name?

Comment: Is `/events` a physical folder on the filesystem? What "error" do you receive?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It says "This page isn't working. <domain> redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. err_too_many_redirects"

Comment: Do you literally just want to redirect `/events`, or `/events/<whatever>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using mod_rewrite:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events[^.] /events.html [R,L]
```

If this should be a permanent redirect then change the `R` to `R=301` only when you are sure its working OK.

You'll need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. It's still not working (404 on this occasion). Here's an example of what I want to redirect... /events/89 to events

Comment: To answer your earlier question @user82217, I've only just taken over the site which I migrated to another host provider. I never got to see the folder setup for the old site.

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow for any files in the directory, not just the directory itself.

Comment: It worked! Well done and thank you for your efforts.